# Excel Date Manipulation Function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel table that contains start times and end times and the added hours. Here is what it looks like

```
***********************************
* Start Time ** End Time ** Hours *
***********************************
***********************************
* 8:00 AM    ** 3:30 PM  ** 7:30  *
***********************************
* 7:30 AM    ** 4:00 PM  ** 8:30  *
***********************************
```

The Hours column contains this function:

```
=TEXT(C3-B3,"h:mm")
```

I need a function that can add up the hours column to find total hours. Every function I have tried has not worked. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your presentation is confusing.  What is Column A?  Why are you starting in Row 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than setting Column D (I guess that’s what it is) to be *`TEXT()`* of the value you want, just set it to the value, `C3-B3`, and *format* it as `h:mm`.  The add them as usual, and format the total as `[h]:mm`.  `h:mm` will display hours modulo 24; `[h]:mm` will allow the hours part to be ≥ 24 (and to be displayed as such).

Comment: That's an excellent answer, succinct but complete and correct

Comment: @barryhoudini: Thanks; that’s high praise, coming from you.